# NSDictionary and Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdictionary, iphonecoredatarecipes

Please I am trying to gain some knowledge in core data. I have so far gotten the hang of creating entities and adding, retrieving and deleting values from this entity.

My question is the following. What are the possible ways of storing `NSDictionary` properties in an entity when using core data?

Comment: I would really recommend to do some reading on the concepts of CoreData (look for CoreData Programming Guide). For the most part - NSDictionary is somewhat equivalent to an entity (NSManagedObject) in memory - both sets of key-value pairs. So the case for storing an NSDictionary as a single attribute/property of an NSManagedObject hints for a flaw in the higher level design.

Answer (score 33):

you should use "Transformable Attributes":

1. open `*.xcdatamodeld` file
2. select entity
3. add attribute (name it for example "**info**") and set the type as "**Transformable**"
4. generate appropriate `NSManagedObject` subclass files (File->New->File ... `NSManagedObject` subclass)
5. open `*.h` file and change type for property "**info**" from **id** to **NSMutableDictionary***

everything else works automatically

for more information see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html

Comment: The default transformer serializes to NSData. And for NSDictionary this is a binary plist.

Comment: So I need to change id to NSDictionary in the ".h" every time I re-gen my NSManagedObjects?  Seems like kind of a pain and definitely something people will forget to do.

Comment: @lostintranslation, no, it's just for convenience. It will work even if you don't change the type.

Comment: The link referenced in the answer here is dead.

Comment: @CyberMew I would assume it would just return a dictionary. However, nothing stops you from using `mutableCopy` to get a NSMutableDictionary. i.e. `[info mutableCopy];`

Comment: should I also set the "Value Transformer" or the "Custom Class" when defining the new property in the model schema?

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to approach this:

a. Create an entity that is representative of the NSDictionary, so that each dictionary key is represented by an entity attribute.

b. If you don't like the above approach where you create a separate entity, you can still store the NSDictionary into a single Core Data field of type NSData, provided that you serialize the NSDictionary to NSData first.

```
//NSDictionary to NSData
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
[archiver encodeObject:dictionary forKey:@"Some Key Value"];
[archiver finishEncoding];
//  data is now ready to use
```

You'd also then need to convert the NSData back to NSDictionary when you read it from Core Data.

```
// NSData to NSDictionary
NSData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self dataFilePath]];
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"Some Key Value"] retain];
[unarchiver finishDecoding];
//  dictionary is now ready to use
```

c. Finally, you can use a persistance framework such as Sensible TableView, where all your data structures are automatically fetched, displayed, and saved. Saves me a ton of code myself.

Comment: The archiving/unarchiving happens automatically if you define the attribute as "Transformable".

Comment: Thank you guys, really appreciate the reply. One more thing, how about if your are looking store these NSDictionary property types in an attribute type of string in core data?

Comment: This all can be done automatically, see Transformable Attributes answer instead. Set the attribute to Transformable and you are done.

Comment: I like this answer, even though it misses the easiest and most competent technical solution (using transformable) - because it is the only answer that doubts the very need for storing NSDictionary in a single attribute - whereas mostly you'd want an Entity to reflect an NSDictionary with its set of attributes - all available as key-value pairs, just like NSDictionary.

Answer (score 4):

Change the attribute type to `Transformable`.

If you are using mogenerator (you very well should), the default type generated for a transformable is `id`.

To have mogenerator generate the specific type `NSDictionary`, you can add a custom key `attributeValueClassName` with value `NSDictionary` for the attribute. Refer to this [screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5021257/242682).